# How to get the ID of the user who is logged into the current session?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, sugarcrm

I need to find the user who is logged into the current session. I tried the following but does not work:
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

```
$.get(CurrentServerAddress + '/service/v4/rest.php', {
    method: "get_user_id",
    input_type: "JSON",
    response_type: "JSON",
    rest_data:'"new_get_user_id":["session":"' + SugarSessionId + '"]'
}, function(data) {
    if (data !== undefined) {
        var userID = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following and it works for me.

```
var userID = '';
    $.get(CurrentServerAddress + '/service/v4/rest.php', {
        method: "get_user_id",
        input_type: "JSON",
        response_type: "JSON",
        rest_data: '[{"session":"' + SugarSessionId + '"}]'
    }, function(data) {
        if (data !== undefined) {
            userID = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'authenticated_user_id'
```

As far as I'm aware that is the sugar crm item in session which you should be looking for, are you requesting that?

Comment: Here's what I found in this regard: http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/6.3/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.3.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.3.0.html

Answer (score 0):

The REST call that you are making requires that you have a SESSION token. Normally, we will setup a *REST* user on our CRM's that can be accessed via REST.